# Write program which verifies Erdős–Straus conjecture

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

Write program, which verifies [Erdős–Straus conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture).
Program should take as input one integer`n` (`3 <= n <= 1 000 000`) and print triple of integers satisfying identity `4/n = 1/x + 1/y + 1/z`, `0 < x < y < z`.

Shortest code wins.

**Some examples:**

```
3 => {1, 4, 12}
4 => {2, 3, 6}
5 => {2, 4, 20}
1009 => {253, 85096, 1974822872}
999983 => {249996, 249991750069, 62495875102311369754692}
1000000 => {500000, 750000, 1500000}
```

Note that your program may print other results for these numbers because there are multiple solutions.

Comment: Does the program need to output every possible solution or only one? For example there are 2 possibilities for n=5.

Comment: Only one is enough.

Comment: It is somewhat misleading that your only test case is not a valid input according to the spec.

Comment: I'll change it, example added durron597.

Comment: I added that example because my research suggested it was a particularly difficult one to do. The hardest ones are primes that are congruent to `{1, 121, 169, 289, 361, 529}` modulo 840.

Comment: According to that definition, These are all *hard*: `1009,1129,1201,1801,2521,2689,3049,3361,3529, 3889,4201,4561,4729,5209,5569,5881,6841,7561,7681,8089`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Ruby, <strike>119</strike> 106 characters

```
f=->s,c,a{m=s.to_i;c<2?m<s||(p a+[m];exit):(1+m...c*s).map{|k|f[s/(1-s/k),c-1,a+[k]]}}
f[gets.to_r/4,3,[]]
```

The code uses minimal bounds for each variable, e.g. `n/4<x<3n/4`, similarly for `y`. Even the last example returns instantaneous (try [here](http://ideone.com/JabsGX)).

Examples:

```
> 12
[4, 13, 156]

> 123
[31, 3814, 14542782]

> 1234
[309, 190654, 36348757062]

> 40881241801
[10220310451, 139272994276206121600, 22828913614743204775214996005450198400]
```

Comment: Cool solution, however bounds are a bit tight, because your program for 1 000 000 finds greater solution (see my example).

Comment: @user2992539 My code returns the lexicographically first solution (250001 < 500000).

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica 62

This plain-vanilla solution works fine--most of the time.

```
f@n_ := FindInstance[4/n == 1/x + 1/y + 1/z && 0 < x < y < z, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

**Examples and Timings (in secs)**

```
AbsoluteTiming[f[63]]
AbsoluteTiming[f[123]]
AbsoluteTiming[f[1003]]
AbsoluteTiming[f[3003]]
AbsoluteTiming[f[999999]]
AbsoluteTiming[f[1000000]]
```

> {0.313671, {{x -> 16, y -> 1009, z -> 1017072}}}
>   {0.213965, {{x -> 31, y -> 3814, z -> 14542782}}}
>   {0.212016, {{x -> 251, y -> 251754, z -> 63379824762}}}
>   {0.431834, {{x -> 751, y -> 2255254, z -> 5086168349262}}}
>   {1.500332, {{x -> 250000, y -> 249999750052, z -> 1201920673328124750000}}}
>   {1.126821, {{x -> 375000, y -> 1125000, z -> 2250000}}}

---

But it does not constitute a complete solution. There are a some numbers that it cannot solve for.  For example,

```
AbsoluteTiming[f[30037]]
AbsoluteTiming[f[130037]]
```

> {2.066699, FindInstance[4/30037 == 1/x + 1/y + 1/z && 0 < x < y < z, {x, y, z}, Integers]}
>   {1.981802, 
>    FindInstance[4/130037 == 1/x + 1/y + 1/z && 0 < x < y < z, {x, y, z},
>      Integers]}

Comment: The right tool for the right job. +1

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa I'd argue that `FindInstance` is not the right tool since it cannot guarantee a result...

Comment: @Howard I was talking about Mathematica, actually

Comment: `Reduce` seems to solve the stubborn cases, though it often takes time.  E.g. 15 minutes to find 82 solutions for n=10037.

Answer (score 3):

## C#

*Disclamer: this is not a serious answer*

This just bruteforces all the possibilities from 1 to 1<<30. It's huge, it's slow, I don't even know if it works correctly, but it follows the specifications quite literally, as it checks the condition every single time, so that's nice.
I haven't tested this because ideone has a 5 second time limit for programs and therefore this won't finish executing.

*(In case anyone was wondering: this is a whopping **308 bytes** long)*

```
static double[]f(double n)
{
    for(double x=1;x<1<<30;x++)
    {
        for(double y=1;y<1<<30;y++)
        {
            for(double z=1;z<1<<30;z++)
            {
                if(4/n==1/x+1/y+1/z)
                    return new[]{x,y,z};
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

*Update: fixed it so it actually works*

Comment: Does not work (hint: integer division).

Comment: Likely it won't work because of round-off errors.

Comment: @user2992539 it works for me, I tested it with `5` as input and it gave the correct result (`2, 4, 20`)

Comment: @HackerCow it may not work for large integers.

Comment: @HackerCow you can certainly save time by starting with y=x+1 and z=y+1.  It will probably be faster to use the equivalent check 4xyz = n(xy+yz+xz), although I accept that is a longer expression and also has rounding problems.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 171 bytes

```python
from sympy import*
def f(n):
 for d in xrange(1,n*n):
  for p in divisors(4*d+n*n):
   q=(4*d+n*n)/p;x=(n+p)/4;y=(n+q)/4
   if (n+p)%4+(n+q)%4+n*x*y%d<1:return x,y,n*x*y/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9LDoMwDET3nMIbJAiWgEI/QDlJ1UWlkDYLnBDSipyeJpFabzyeZ2ls7exL0WHfhVEzrG7WDuSslbEs4ZMAkVHeJyCUAQ6SYDMPek5ZjcQiiEQHwuVHrsqsWct48aOwjP@51MM2ZlTovGwHF9TiVViSAqKftkV0fSe2MZfya92byb6ND0aH0Sz5HjIpZN4abPGIdVV12Pm6NEGHwvOpqw/dPR4B2kiyQBjf2b8)

The first answer fast enough to be exhaustively tested.  This is able to find solutions for all 3 ≤ *n* ≤ 1000000 in about 24 minutes *total*, for an average of about 1.4 milliseconds each.

#### How it works

Rewrite 4/*n* = 1/*x* + 1/*y* + 1/*z* as *z* = *n*·*x*·*y*/*d*, where *d* = 4·*x*·*y* − *n*·*x* − *n*·*y*.  Then we can factor 4·*d* + *n*<sup>2</sup> = (4·*x* − *n*)·(4·*y* − *n*), which gives us a much faster way to search for *x* and *y* as long as *d* is small.  Given *x* < *y* < *z*, we can at least prove *d* < 3·*n*<sup>2</sup>/4 (hence the bound on the outer loop), although in practice it tends to be much smaller—95% of the time, we can use *d* = 1, 2, or 3.  The worst case is *n* = 769129, for which the smallest *d* is 1754 (this case takes about 1 second).

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 117

```
n=input();r=range;z=0
while 1:
 z+=1
 for y in r(z):
  for x in r(y):
    if 4*x*y*z==n*(y*z+x*z+x*y):print x,y,z;exit()
```

Example:

```
16 --> 10 12 15
```

Nothing too special.

Comment: Why do you define a function if you're only going to call it once?

Comment: @isaacg It needs to stop somehow, but using `exit()` instead does shorten it.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 99 bytes

```
f[n_]:=(x=1;(w=While)[1>0,y=1;w[y<=x,z=1;w[z<=y,If[4/n==1/x+1/y+1/z,Return@{x,y,z}];++z];++y];++x])
```

It's fairly naive brute force, so it doesn't really scale well. I'm definitely going to get to a million (so feel free to consider this invalid for the time being). `n = 100` takes half a second, but `n = 300` already takes 12 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## [Golflua](http://mniip.com/misc/conv/golflua/) 75

Reads `n` from prompt (after invocation in terminal), but basically iterates as [Calvin's Hobbies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/34860/11376) solution does:

```
n=I.r()z=1@1~@y=1,z-1~@x=1,y-1?4*x*y*z==n*(y*z+x*z+x*y)w(n,x,y,z)~$$$z=z+1$
```

An ungolfed Lua version of the above is

```
n=io.read()
z=1
while 1 do
   for y=1,z-1 do
      for x=1,y-1 do
         if 4*x*y*z==n*(y*z+x*z+x*y) then
            print(n,x,y,z)
            return
         end
      end
   end
   z=z+1
end
```

Examples:

```
n=6     -->     3      4     12
n=12    -->     6     10     15
n=100   -->    60     75    100
n=1600  -->  1176   1200   1225
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 134

Well, I posted an answer here before, but it wasn't really that serious. As it so happens, I'm very often very bored, so I golfed it a little bit.

It calculates all the examples *technically* correctly (I haven't tried the last two because, again, ideone inforces a 5 second time limit) but the first ones yield the correct result (not necessarily the result you calculated, but a correct one). It strangely outputs the number out of order (I have no clue why) and it gives `10, 5, 2` for `5` (which is a valid answer according to wikipedia).

134 bytes for now, I could probably golf it up a bit more.

```
float[]f(float n){float x=1,y,z;for(;x<1<<30;x++)for(y=1;y<x;y++)for(z=1;z<y;z++)if(4/n==1/x+1/y+1/z)return new[]{x,y,z};return null;}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Haskell -  150 characters

`main = getLine >>= \n -> (return $ head $ [(x,y,z) | x <- [1..y], y <- [1..z], z <- [1..], (4/n') == (1/x) + (1/y) + (1/z)])
    where n' = read n`

This ought to work, but I've not compiled it yet. It's almost certainly very very slow. It checks every possible triplet of valid integers, and should stop when it sees a set that works.